# How to use fetch to upload binary file in react native with react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, blob, fetch-api

I have some trouble in uploading file to server,because I can't find a method to convert img to  binary data struct.

a success request like this in swagger
[image]

[image]

```
// upload function 
const UploadImg = async (img: any) => {
  // img  from  react-native-image-crop-picker
  const fromData = new FormData();
  fromData.append('file', `${img.data}`);

  return fetch(`${API_URL_R}/upload`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: fromData, // this should be binary 
  })
};

// use
// import ImagePicker from  'react-native-image-crop-picker'
 ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: true,
      includeBase64: true,
    }).then(async image => {
      await UploadImg(image);
    });
```

Comment: You can send the file as Base64 to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image received in ImagePicker.openPicker you will receive image.path, image.filename and image.mime and then you can upload image as below

Note: file name can also be received as
let filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.length)

Upload Image

```
 const UploadImg = async () => {

 const fromData = new FormData();

  fromData.append("file", {
    name: filename,
    type: mime,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android"
        ? filepath
        : filepath.replace("file://", "")
  });
 
var url = uploadImageUrl

const response = await fetch(url, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {   
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    Accept: "application/json",
    Authorization: authToken
  },
body: fromData, 
})

}
```

Comment: glad i could help you :)